# Rails scope for alphabetical ordering with string manipulation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to create a scope in my Rails model.

I have a content with many images.
Any image is a Carrierwave file.

I need to create a scope to order the images using the filename.

Usually I have a scope like this:

```
scope :cities_by_name, -> { cities.order(name: :asc) }
```

But with my images scope I have two issues:

1. The filename for a carrierwave model is `image.file.filename`
2. I'm adding some random string in front of the file name before saving, so for my order I need to strip these characters.

Basically I need to order my images for

```
image.file.filename.slice!(6)
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You could user raw sql in the order clause and use something like Postgres' `substring()` function, possibly. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-string.html

Answer (score 0):

In case your aware the about the length of random string appended before the file name. The below solution can work for you:

```
scope :images_by_name, -> { select('images.file_name, RIGHT(images.file_name, LENGTH(images.file_name) - 4) as updated_name').order('updated_name asc') }
```